# Push changes to bitbucket using atom

Tags: package, push, atom-editor

I am using the text editor Atom and it should be possible to upload directly to bitbucket from atom. I found a thread here on stackoverflow someone asked for this and someone recommended git-plus package. I did download this package but it tells me i need to edit user.email and user.name variable in gitconfig file. But it doesnt say anywhere where i can find this gitconfig file. I found a few config files but none of them have these variables. Is this gitconfig file in my .git folder in my project or is it somewhere in atom? I hope someone here can help me with this

Comment: These are jsut the configrution for "git" itself - that is, if your bitbucket repo is using git and nor mercurial.
Just search for "git configure email"

Comment: Okey thanks. But where do i search for git configure email?

Comment: Oh okey. Thank you for the help !

Comment: Okey. I fixed the variables. However i still have some problem. if i click package menu in atom and then i go to git-plus and click "add all + commit + push" then it doesnt really upload it for me. For some reason it looks like it only add and commit but doesnt really push. So i have to do it from the git bash console by using command "git push -u origin --all"

Answer (score 0):

Set up git in your shell to use bitbucket as the remote repo.

You will first need to sort that basic Git config thing about the emails:

```
$ git config --global --get user.name 
Your Name Here
$ git config --global --get user.email
your_email@someplace.com
```

If you don't have these values already added, then simply add them. Put your current directory someplace under the root of your `atom` repository (or, if you want to use the `--global` parameters [recommended]), then anywhere will do, really so long as it's your login you're working with.)

```
$ git config [--global] user.name "Your Name"
$ git config [--global] user.email "your_email@somplace.com"
```

First set up your ssh key so you don't have to type your password on every command. Once that's done, then go to the Git repo you set up for your Atom project. Most likely that's in the top level of my project. Go there and...

```
$ git remote -v
$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:youruid/yourrepo.git
```

Now try it from the shell to make sure all is working:

```
$ git push
```

It's very likely you'll get a message similar to:

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Follow the advice given, then, if you're feeling particularly paranoid, make a change to any file in the repo -- using `atom` if you like, doesn't matter -- and try it all again:

```
$ git add -u
$ git commit [-v]
...
$ git push
```

This time, it should go off without a hitch.

Now back to `atom`...

If you've configured things there so that `atom` can access your Git repo locally, there should now be a `Fetch` widget in the lower right corner:
[image: Lower Right Corner]

If you make a change now in `atom`, you'll see this change to `Push`... with the functionality to match.

The `GitHub` widget still doesn't do anything -- which is mildly annoying -- but I believe you might be able to find an `atom` package out there that does similar things.